# jQuery hover effect based on parent attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I written some code that changes an image and fades the opacity when and image is hovered over - giving the hovered effect.

I am now trying to modify the code so if the hovered image's parent div has a value attribute of "added", the hover affect won't trigger on that image.

How do I stop the hovered effect on images, with parents that have a value attribute of "added"?

This is what my HTML looks like:

Hover disabled, value attribute is "added".

```
<button class="add_list_button" value="added"><img class="test" src="/assets/heart-empty.png"/></button>
```

Hover enabled, no value attribute:

```
<button class="add_list_button" value=""><img class="test" src="/assets/heart-empty.png"/></button>
```

This is what my jQuery looks like:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    var value = $('.add_list_button').val();
    var img = $(".add_list_button").children('img');
   $(img).hover(function(){
   $(this).attr('src','assets/heart-full.png').animate({opacity: 0.7}, 400);
   },function(){
    $(this).attr('src','assets/heart-empty.png').animate({opacity: 1}, 400);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use css3 selector for that  purpose. Instead of:

```
var img = $(".add_list_button").children('img');
```

use

```
var img = $(".add_list_button:not([value='added'])").children('img');
```

your whole code will be:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    var value = $('.add_list_button').val();
   var img = $(".add_list_button:not([value='added'])").children('img');
   $(img).hover(function(){
   $(this).attr('src','assets/heart-full.png').animate({opacity: 0.7}, 400);
   },function(){
    $(this).attr('src','assets/heart-empty.png').animate({opacity: 1}, 400);
  });
});
```

I think you can simplify this code. It can be like this:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
   $(".add_list_button:not([value='added']) img").hover(function(){
       $(this).attr('src','assets/heart-full.png').animate({opacity: 0.7}, 400);
       },function(){
       $(this).attr('src','assets/heart-empty.png').animate({opacity: 1}, 400);
    });
});
```

EDIT:
added click event

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
   $(".add_list_button:not([value='added']) img")
   .hover(function(){
         $(this)
           .attr('src','assets/heart-full.png')
           .animate({opacity: 0.7}, 400);
       },function(){
         $(this)
           .attr('src','assets/heart-empty.png')
           .animate({opacity: 1}, 400);
       }
    )
    .click(function(){
       $(this)
           .unbind('mouseenter mouseleave click')
           .animate({opacity: 1}, 400)
           .attr('src','assets/heart-full.png')
       .parents('.add_list_button').val('added')
       ;
    });
});
```

Comment: I have implemented the code - and it mostly works. However I have another button that clicks and tries to set the image to ('src','assets/heart-full.png') and attribute to "added", however I am unable to set the image. If I remove your code I am able to set the image. Basically on hover I want to change the image (as above) but I also want to change the image when clicked! How do I add this?

Comment: do you want to add the same behavior for both - the hover and for the click events or different?

Comment: Yes. So basically on Hover change the src attribute temporally as above. And on Click change the src attribute permanently. I have a button like with this jquery in it: $(this).children('img').attr("src","assets/heart-full.png");

Comment: So when the button is clicked the button changes image, and the value is set to added. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think I may have confused things - I wanted to keep the image changed even after the click! Is this possible?

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't understand what do you need. you can add your desired image in the click event scope on the line wich looks like this: .attr('src','assets/heart-full.png')   what did it now? when you click the image it must be stay changed

Comment: Yes when i press to click it shows the image, however when i finish the click the image disappears.

Comment: are you sure you copied whole code?     does `.unbind('mouseenter mouseleave click')`    presented in your code?  I have created the fiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/pohn6a4s/]
 there image remains unchanged after click (just changing opacity to 1)

Comment: I have added it! The Fiddle has disappeared!

Answer (score 1):

you don't need jQuery, you can do by css attribute selector.

```css
.add_list_button img:hover {
  border:1px solid red;
}

.add_list_button[value="added"] img:hover {
  border:0 solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add_list_button" ><img class="test" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Not added"/></button>
<div>
<br/>
</div>
<button class="add_list_button" value="added"><img class="test" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=added"/></button>
```